# In the book Flask.Web.Development, Why just db.session.add() and no db.session.commit()?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm reading Flask.Web.Development, and read codes like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.name.data).first() 
        if user is None:
            user = User(username = form.name.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            session['known'] = False
        else:
            session['known'] = True
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html',
        form = form, name = session.get('name'), known = session.get('known', False))
```

The line 7, why just db.session.add(user) and no db.session.commit()?
It just add to the session but don't commit to the database. But database was indeed updated.

Comment: Two possibilities: the database was configured to auto-commit, or there is *other* code that commits changes after view has completed, like in a `after_request()` handler.

Comment: I got it, I have set SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True. Thank you!